# VLC not changing cover art

Tags: vlc

I'm using VLC Media Player v3.0.16 (Vetinari) on Ubuntu 22.04.  I have some .mp3 files I obtained from an external source.  The files came with cover art images that I'd like to change, but I can't change them.

I've searched for "VLC how to change cover art", and I've followed the procedure I found from the results.  With VLC open and playing the file, I access the 'Media Information' dialog window.  The cover art appears in the lower right.  If I right-click that image, the context menu gives me the options "Download cover art" and "Add cover art from file".  I select "Add cover art from file", and a "Choose cover art" dialog opens.  In it, I navigate to the cover art image I want and select it.  The new cover art then appears in the VLC player.

The problem is that the selection doesn't "save".  If I close and reopen the file, or even if it finishes playing and loops back to the start, then the cover art reverts to that originally provided with the file.  There is no UI option I can see for "Permanently save this cover art selection".

My normal login user owns the .mp3 files and has 'rw' permission on them.  The files don't appear to be "locked" in any other way I can find, so my best guess is that it's not a permissions problem.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a VLC bug?

Comment: As it seems from the forum ( https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=159297 ) it's a VLC bug.